# Aurelia leaking bindings

Tags: javascript, memory-leaks, aurelia

I have noticed that a large portion of our bindings are leaking memory. 
The problems seems to boil down to `removeSubscriber` not being called for everything that was once being added by `addSubscriber`.

I added a piece of code to the `aurelia-binding.js` to track these objects (Binding objects that are stored in `_callablesRest` array) and print them out.

I ended up seeing `_callablesRest` list growing to thousands of bindings and this grows as you use the app.

I have noticed a known issue in older versions of Aurelia (https://github.com/aurelia/binding/issues/585) which is fixed but even with that change `_callablesRest` keeps growing.

Anyone has noticed anything?

Comment: Not sure if StackOverflow is the right place for an answer, have you filed a GitHub issue yet?

Comment: Thanks Jesse, wasn't sure if this is really a bug. But I am now sure

Answer (score 0):

Apparently a known bug https://github.com/aurelia/templating-resources/issues/310#issuecomment-406576649

The workaround is to wrap the repeat in a div.